# How exactly does a computer know what device is connected on the USB port?

Tags: usb, midi

I am working on a mini that uses USB.

This is probably something that I can get in the huge USB docs but if I can get a brief response I'll be happy. So since almost all devices interface with the computer via USB, how does the computer know what devices are connected? Do the devices some packets with info regarding device info (e.g memory, sound card, joystick)? If so, how exactly is the data packaged?

Comment: Yes, they communicate.

Comment: Upon connection, every USB device is considered generic. The device then goes through enumeration. During this process, the device tells the host who it is and what it needs. The host then recognizes the device and loads the appropriate drivers. The device is now something specific.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1587144/how-does-a-computer-know-which-device-is-connected-to-the-usb-port

Comment: Thank you, Andy! But do you perhaps have any detailed idea of how exactly this happens...from a low-level perspective?

Comment: @skmbathakatlego what have you learned **from your own research** so far?   Questions here are reserved only for what is left over *after* making a basic attempt yourself.  The point of Stack Exchange is not to re-create *documentation* or *tutorials* on demand.

Comment: @vini_i Thank you soo much. This makes good sense. Could you please refer me to some link or book where I can read more about this?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Noted!

Comment: https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-50420.pdf There are newer editions of USB Complete but this is enough to get your whistle wet.

Comment: @vini_i I really appreciate this :-) ! Thank you!

Comment: "Could you please refer me to some link or book" requests for off-site references are off topic.  Try a web search on the term "USB enumeration"

Comment: @ChrisStratton Mr. Chris, just to balance you a bit. There are millions of sources on the web and a new member in the field just like me needs to have some sense of direction or else he'll probably get lost. There is also no "wrong" or "right" way of asking a question. Additionally, this is where my research starts....but....thank you!

Comment: As this site has rules, there are very much wrong ways of asking here, which is to say posting questions which *violate those rules*, as yours does.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As I said, I am new. Thanks for pointing that out. I will check out the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at "Universal Serial Bus Specification" Version 2.0 Sections 9.1.2 and 11.12.6

The specification can be found at...

https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-20-specification

Get the zip file containing all the base specificaiton PDFs and then look in usb_20.pdf.

Comment: Realistically the spec is probably *not* the best place to look for an introduction.  A web search on "USB enumeration" would be.

Comment: As in Many cases, the Wikipedia article to USB is not a bad start... it contains a lot of information to device classes, compound devices,...